# Get the store ID for multi store setup with opencart

Tags: php, opencart

We have a multi-store set up and I wanted to change the template slightly for each store. I had a good look through the code already in place and found these:

```
$this->config->get('config_store_id')

$this->load->model('setting/store');
$results = $this->model_setting_store->getStores();

$this->model_setting_setting->getSetting('config', $order_info['store_id']);
```

The first line only ever returns the default store ID. I would want this to work even if we have not order details.

**What is the most reliable way to get the store ID?**

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Do you know the solution or it just solved automatically ?

Comment: I wasn't sure what was really wrong in the end I just used `$this->config->get('config_store_id')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current store ID is in `$this->config->get('config_store_id')`

It gets changed to the correct store ID in this code in the `index.php` file

```
if ($store_query->num_rows) {
    $config->set('config_store_id', $store_query->row['store_id']);
} else {
    $config->set('config_store_id', 0);
}
```

Comment: Not sure what the issue was when I was testing this before. Thanks