# Get current store id in opencart

Tags: php, opencart

i try to show different header image in  frontend based on `store id` mean every store has different header image .

the problem is how to echo current store_id in frontend (in `header`)

so i can proceed with my code something like below :

```
<?php
if($store_id == '1') {  // 1 is default store
    //echo image here   
}
else {  //if not default show different image
    //echo image here   
}
?>
```

*Opencart version : 1.4.9.6*

Comment: [View this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916282/get-the-store-id-for-multi-store-setup-with-opencart)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The current `store_id` of Your store is in `$this->config->get('config_store_id')`.

That means if You need it in the template, edit header controller (`catalog/controller/common/header.php`) - some in the `index()` function add this code (id it is not present already):

```
$this->data['store_id'] = $this->config->get('config_store_id');
```

Then in Your `header.tpl` of Your template (`catalog/view/theme/<YOUR_THEME>/template/common/header.tpl`) use it this way:

```
<?php if ($tore_id == 0) { ?>
<div>Main store</div>
<?php } else { ?>
<div>Subdomain store</div>
<?php } ?>
```

or this way:

```
<div class="container-<?php echo $store_id; ?>"> ... </div>
```

It is upon You.

**EDIT:** Also consider moving on with newer OpenCart (latest is 1.5.4.1 as of 15<sup>th</sup> December, 2012) - it is worth the redesign and the functions and gadgets it has.

Comment: It's worth the redesign sure but considering most users of 1.4.X have had large modifications that are core edits (vQmod was relatively new back then) then it is most likely going to be a nightmare to upgrade